# Redis: Is it necessary to rebalance hash slots after adding a new node to the cluster

Tags: redis

I have added a new node to the Redis Cluster. I have been adding keys. However, I found that none of the keys is allotted to the hash slot on the new node.

After rebalancing, I've noticed that the keys are assigned to the new node as well.

Comment: Yes you need to move slots, auto resharding is only supported on Redis Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if a shard is added to the cluster then you need to choose the hash slots from the other shards which you need to transfer to the added shard. Otherwise the added shard is going to sit idle.